# Unable to get variable expansion in docker exec command in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, docker, shell, jenkins

I am getting the java version of running inside a container and creating a json file with the following command block in my jenkins pipeline:

```
sh "docker exec -i $CONTAINER_NAME bash -c JAVA_VERSION=\$(java --version | head -n1 | awk '{print \$2}'); BUILD_METADATA=\$(echo '{\"environment\": {\"language\": {\"java\": {\"version\":\"'\$JAVA_VERSION'\"}}}}'); echo \$BUILD_METADATA > \${WORKSPACE}/build_metadata.json"
```

The docker exec command works on my local computer as follows:

```
docker exec -i $CONTAINER_NAME bash -c JAVA_VERSION=\$(java --version | head -n1 | awk '{print \$2}'); BUILD_METADATA=\$(echo '{\"environment\": {\"language\": {\"java\": {\"version\":\"'\$JAVA_VERSION'\"}}}}'); echo \$BUILD_METADATA > \${WORKSPACE}/build_metadata.json
```

However, when I run the first command block (consisting of 3 commands) in my Jenkins pipeline, the json file is produced but the $JAVA_VERSION is empty. The Jenkins logs are as follows:

```
++ java --version
19:13:57  ++ head -n1
19:13:57  ++ awk '{print $2}'
19:13:57  + docker exec -i ib3bh bash -c JAVA_VERSION=11.0.21
19:13:57  ++ echo '{"environment": {"language": {"java": {"version":""}}}}'
19:13:57  + BUILD_METADATA='{"environment": {"language": {"java": {"version":""}}}}'
19:13:57  + echo '{"environment":' '{"language":' '{"java":' '{"version":""}}}}'
```

Can i get assistance in understanding what is happening and why the $JAVA_VERSION variable is not being passed to the BUILD_METADATA? The version key is empty.

Running the command locally (without the sh) runs with no issues and creates a valid json.

Comment: I don't understand how this code can work even without the  `sh`. `bash -c` takes the first word as a command, and the remaining words as arguments. The first word is `JAVA_VERSION=\$(java`, and since the `(` is not escaped, you would get an error message. Try on the command line: `bash -c J=\$(echo x)`, and you get an error as well. Indeed, if I just do a `echo docher exec ...` with your docker command, I get a syntax error as well. If this works for you, I wonder what interactive shell you used when running the `docker` command.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `docker exec` here, nor do you need to do *all* of the work in a shell.  Jenkins has reasonable support for [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/), and since Groovy is a full-featured language, you can do things like construct the JSON object in native code.

Let's say you have a Jenkins Docker image object in a variable.  You can run the `java -version` command in a temporary container based on that image, and collect its result into a Groovy variable.

```
def image = docker.image('myname/myimage')
def javaVersion
image.inside() {
  javaVersion = sh(script: 'java -version | head -n1 | awk "{print \$2}"',
                   returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

Now that you have that, you can assemble the metadata object as a Groovy map

```
def metadata = [
  'environment': [
    'language': [
      'java': [
        'version': javaVersion
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

and finally ask Jenkins to write out the JSON file

```bash
writeJSON(file: 'build_metadata.json', json: metadata)
```

Note that, in all of this, we've only had to use one backslash for quoting punctuation, and we've never used `docker exec`.  If you need to add more data to this object, you can insert it in the Groovy Jenkinsfile and ask your IDE to reïndent it, without having to worry about quotes and backslashes and curly braces inside a very long shell command.